# C++ || Adding two matrice arrays - easier way to output?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, matrix, format

I'm doing some self study on C++ and have just being doing some chapter on arrays, loops etc. There are a bunch of exercises and the one I'm referencing is quite simple. Initialise two matrices of two rows and three columns.

Output the contents of the matrices (formatted as specified), then perform an addition which is held in a third matrice. Output the third array with the addition done. The code I have works but I'm thinking there's a better way to do the output rather than address each matrice element? I'm thinking of another loop given this is the chapter preceding the exercise, or is this way acceptable?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int amatrix[2][3]=
    {
        {-5, 2, 8},
        {1, 0, 0},
    };

    int bmatrix[2][3]=
    {
        {1, 0, 2},
        {0, 3, -6},
    };

    int cmatrix[2][3]=
    {
        {0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0},
    };

    //add generated matrices
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j =0; j <= 2; j++)
        {
            cmatrix[i][j]=amatrix[i][j]+bmatrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    //output to screen - NEED ADVICE FROM HERE
    cout << "A= " << endl;
    cout << amatrix[0][0] << ", " << amatrix[0][1] << ", " << amatrix[0][2] << endl;
    cout << amatrix[1][0] << ", " << amatrix[1][1] << ", " << amatrix[1][2] << endl << endl;
    cout << "B= " << endl;
    cout << bmatrix[0][0] << ", " << bmatrix[0][1] << ", " << bmatrix[0][2] << endl;
    cout << bmatrix[1][0] << ", " << bmatrix[1][1] << ", " << bmatrix[1][2] << endl << endl;
    cout << "C= " << endl;
    cout << cmatrix[0][0] << ", " << cmatrix[0][1] << ", " << cmatrix[0][2] << endl;
    cout << cmatrix[1][0] << ", " << cmatrix[1][1] << ", " << cmatrix[1][2] << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this would be much nicer as a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cout << amatrix[i][j]` in a for loop

Comment: ah, of course - so simple. I was trying to output it in the initial for loop.